# How to suppress query cache logging in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a **lot** of `CACHE (0.0ms)...` messages showing up in my Rails 4 applciation which is making is difficult to see things that I'm really concerned with. How do I suppress these messages while in development?

Comment: If I were you I'd tackle the source rather than just suppress the log messages

Comment: ^ Isn't it good that Rails is caching the value and not doing another lookup? Why would this be a problem other than it cluttering up the log?

Comment: It's still less efficient than non hitting the query cache - rails still has to construct the active record objects from the cached query results

Answer (score 0):

checkout this clip from [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/402-better-errors-railspanel)
it shows a nice chrome tool to debug.even if you do see the cache logs, all the info will be better separated and you can see other errors as well.